# Unable to load the payment options in paytm js checkout

Tags: javascript, html, paytm

I am working with Paytm gateway and I want to implement JS Checkout, but I'm unable to load the banks and options of payment.

Below is all the code that I'm using:

```js
                async function onScriptLoad(){
                    var data = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/payment`,{
                                method:"GET",
                                headers:{
                                    Accept:"application/json",
                                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                                },
                            }).then(response=>response.json()).catch(err=>console.log(err));
    
                    var Jsondata = JSON.parse(data)      
                    console.log(JSON.parse(data))
    
                    var token = await fetch(`https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=Muctvj23768431537109&orderId=${Jsondata.body.orderId}`,{
                                method:"POST",
                                headers:{
                                    Accept:"application/json",
                                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                                },
                                body:data
                            }).then(response=>response.json()).catch(err=>console.log(err));
    
                            console.log(token)
            var config = {
                    "root": "",
                    "flow": "DEFAULT",
                    "data": {
                        "orderId": Jsondata.body.orderId, /* update order id */
                        "token": token, /* update token value */
                        "tokenType": "TXN_TOKEN",
                        "amount": "1.00" /* update amount */
                    },
                    "payMode": {
                            "order": ['CARD']
                        },
                    "handler": {
                        "notifyMerchant": function(eventName,data){
                        console.log("notifyMerchant handler function called");
                        console.log("eventName => ",eventName);
                        console.log("data => ",data);
                        } 
                    }
            };
    
                    if(window.Paytm && window.Paytm.CheckoutJS){
                        window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.onLoad(function excecuteAfterCompleteLoad() {
                            // initialze configuration using init method 
                            window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.init(config).then(function onSuccess() {
                                // after successfully updating configuration, invoke JS Checkout
                                console.log("success")
                                window.Paytm.CheckoutJS.invoke();
                            }).catch(function onError(error){
                                console.log("error => ",error);
                            });
                        });
                    }  
                }
```

I am new to this; any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether you are using the correct mid and other configurations or not. If details are correct please raise a query at Paytm Developers support